# Javascript code that disables an element only works for chrome

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, firefox, cross-browser

I am kinda new to javascript.

I have current javascript code that I have placed on the end of my website that disables a button if a certain condition is met. However, this code only on chrome, when testing on firefox and internet explorer, it seems that the code doesn't work at all.

Here is the javascript code:

```
/** Email checker **/ 

console.log("Beginning of Code"); 
var reject = [
    "gmail.com",
    "yahoo.com",
    "msn.com",
    "rocketmail.com",
    "aol.com",
    "prodigy.com",
    "bellsouth.net", 
    "hotmail.com",
    "live.com",
    "icloud.com",
    "justenough.com",
    "blueridgeinventory.com",
    "jda.com"
    ]; 
var email = document.querySelector("input[name='Email']");
var submitButton = document.querySelector("input[type='submit']"); 
var re = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\    [[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;

function insertAfter(referenceNode, newNode) {

    if (document.getElementById("email-warning")){
        var element = document.getElementById("email-warning");
        element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
    } 
        referenceNode.parentNode.insertBefore(newNode, referenceNode.nextSibling);
}

var validateEmail = function() { 
    var input = email.value; 
    input = input.replace(/ /g,''); 

    var value = input.split('@'); 
    var isValidEmail = re.test(input); 
    var paragraphNode = document.createElement("p"); 
    paragraphNode.setAttribute("id","email-warning"); 

    if (isValidEmail) {
    /** Email is in rejected list **/ 
        var textNode = document.createTextNode("Your Email is Valid");              
        paragraphNode.setAttribute("style", "color: green; ");              
        submitButton.disabled = false; 
        submitButton.style.opacity = "1"; 

        if (reject.indexOf(value[1]) >= 0){
            var textNode = document.createTextNode("Please Enter Company Email");               
            paragraphNode.setAttribute("style", "color: red; ");   
            submitButton.disabled  = true; 
            submitButton.style.opacity = "0.5"; 
        }

    } else {
        var textNode = document.createTextNode("Your Email Invalid");               
        paragraphNode.setAttribute("style", "color: red; "); 
        submitButton.disabled  = true; 
        submitButton.style.opacity = "0.5"; 
    }

    paragraphNode.appendChild(textNode); 
    insertAfter(email, paragraphNode);

    console.log("This ran"); 

}

email.addEventListener('keyup', validateEmail); 
console.log("This ran"); 

/** Get the Previous page referral **/


var oldURL = document.referrer;  
var referringPageInput = document.getElementById("referringPage"); 

referringPageInput.setAttribute("value", oldURL ); 
console.log(oldURL);
```

**The code inside the function EmailValidate is where it seems to fail.**
I have checked the console and all the variables are being defined, but for some reason the functionality is not working for internet explorer and firefox. I read that the style computer is different for those web browsers, but it never gave me an alternative. Any help is appreciated thank you.

By failing I mean that it simply is not working. There is no error or warning log on the console. I tried adding a console.log to see if the code is failing at a certain point but everything seems to be working fine.

Comment: "it seems to fail" can you please explain what that means? Does it not do something you expect it to? Can you identify which line that is by making a [mcve]?

Comment: Instead of `setAttribute`, Try `paragraphNode.style.color = 'green';`